# Catel MVVM Application Code Structure

Tags: mvvm, catel

Currently I am exploring MVVM framework for developing WinRT and Windows Phone application. I found Catel MVVM framework promising which is offering many features. I have also gone through various sample examples with catel mvvm available on codeplex. However most of those examples are structured in single visual studio project. By single project what I mean is there is one visual studio project for WinRT application which holds models, viewmodels and views and separate project for Windows phone application.
I am planning to structure my code in such a way that I can share code between WinRT and Windows Phone application.
e.g.

Common

- Project 1: Business Service
- Project 2: Model
- Project 3: View Models

WinRT

- Project 4: WinRT Application specific code (Views etc.)

Win Phone

- Project 5: Windows Phone Application specific code(Views etc.)

Now my question is as I understand Catel uses some conventions to locate viewmodel, is it possible to structure application code as mentioned above? If yes then how? Is there any sample example code which I can take help from? Any help in this regard is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can even use separate assemblies to resolve naming conventions (you can fully customize them as you can see in the [documentation](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/Locators+and+naming+conventions)).

Comment: Thanks Greet for documentation link. What I understood from documentation is I can let my view know where my viewmodels are located using viewmodellocator. However I am still not clear about usage of ViewModelLocator and ViewLocator. I have questions here.  Do I need to write any bootstrapper to configure naming conventions? Or is there any method where I can register it?

Comment: Also how do I let my viewmodels know about models?

Comment: You should register the naming conventions in your application startup (like App.xaml.cs). You might also consider this:

http://www.geertvanhorrik.com/2013/06/28/assembly-constructors-and-initializers-using-c/

Comment: ViewModels know about models because you use them in there. There is no mapping / naming convention there.